# mocking a angularjs value to be reused within different tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a angularjs service which makes use of a angular value to store the username.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myapp.services', [])
    .service('authService', AuthService)
    .value('authStore', {
      username: null
    });

  AuthService.$inject = ['authStore'];

  function AuthService(authStore) {
    var svc = this;
    var _username = authStore.username;
    svc.isLoggedIn = IsLoggedIn;
    svc.logout = Logout;
    svc.login = Login;
    svc.getUsername = GetUsername;

    function IsLoggedIn() {
      return _username != null && _username && _username != '';
    }

    function Logout() {
      authStore.username = null;
      _username = null;
    }

    function GetUsername() {
      return _username;
    }

    function Login(username) {
      authStore.username = username;
      _username = username;
    }
  }
})();
```

and I'm using jasmine to try and test my isLoggedin method. 
So my tests would be;

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    describe('Auth Service Tests', function () {
        beforeEach(module('ionic'));
        beforeEach(module('myapp.services'));
        var provider
        var authStore;
        var authService;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module(function ($provide) {
                authStore = {
                    username: null
                };
                $provide.value('authStore', authStore);
            });
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function (_authService_) {
            authService = _authService_;
        }));

        describe('isLoggedIn', function () {
            it('should be false the username is null.', function () {
                spyOn(authStore, 'username').and.returnValue(null);
                expect(authService.isLoggedIn()).toBe(false); //success
                //(this is because the authStore is initialized with username: null, not because of the spyOn line above)
                console.log(authService.getUsername()); //null
            });

            it('should be true the username has a value', function () {
                spyOn(authStore, 'username').and.returnValue('test');
                expect(authService.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);  //Failed
                console.log(authService.getUsername()); //null
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

The problem i'm having is that. I'm unable to change the return value of the username in authStore. its always returning the mock value which i set in the beforeEach.

1) Am i missing something here??

2) Whats the proper way to mock an angularjs value to be used in a test. in a scenario like this where it needs to be changed from test to test???

Answer (score 0):

First, you're trying to spy on a field of type string (`authStore.username`). That isn't possible. A string is not a function. It can't return anything. Only have a value. A spy is used to replace a function by another, fake one. Not to change the value of a string.

But that isn't necessary anyway: since it's just a string, there is nothing to spy on. Just set the value you would like it to have. You don't even need to provide a fake implementation of it, since the fake implementation is identical to the real one:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    describe('Auth Service Tests', function () {
        beforeEach(module('ionic', 'myapp.services'));

        var authStore;
        var authService;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_authService_, _authStore_) {
            authService = _authService_;
            authStore = _authStore_;
        }));

        describe('isLoggedIn', function () {
            it('should be false the username is null.', function () {
                authStore.username = null;

                expect(authService.isLoggedIn()).toBe(false);
                console.log(authService.getUsername());
            });

            it('should be true the username has a value', function () {
                authStore.username = 'test';

                expect(authService.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
                console.log(authService.getUsername());
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your input.
But it seems the problem is not solved.
I tried using your approach. But the 2nd Test 'should be true the username has a value' fails. becos the authStore.username is null, even though i set it to 'test'

Comment: Your code is badly designed, and the test shows it: what's the point of storing the username in another variable of AuthService, since it's already in authStore? Or, put in another way, what's the point of having a separat authStore service, since the AuthService is perfectly capable of storing the username without its help? Having two separate services to store the same thing is not a good idea. The AuthService reads the username from authStore when it's instantiated, and never reads it after anymore. But your test changes authSTore.username, and assumes that AuthService should see the change

Comment: I agree my service was badly designed.
I've created a separate authStore becos, I need to share username between services. And i didn't want them to depend on the full authService. Just to retrive username. 
My thinking was flawed. 
Thanks for ur input.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with the help of @JD Nizet's answer. Posting it here becos it might be a learning point for anyone who runs into the same problem.

1st off, the solution provided by @JD Nizet didn't work, and the reason was My service was poorly designed.

I should store the full authStore as a private a variable in the service not just the username.

> var _username = authStore.username;

should change to

> var _authStore = authStore;

then i have to update my methods to use the new _authStore and the tests work!
Here is the complete service with the change;

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myapp.services', [])
    .service('authService', AuthService)
    .value('authStore', {
      username: null
    });

  AuthService.$inject = ['authStore'];

  function AuthService(authStore) {
    var svc = this;
    var _authStore = authStore;
    svc.isLoggedIn = IsLoggedIn;
    svc.logout = Logout;
    svc.login = Login;
    svc.getUsername = GetUsername;

    function IsLoggedIn() {
      return _authStore.username != null && _authStore.username && _authStore.username != '';
    }

    function Logout() {
      _authStore.username = null;
    }

    function GetUsername() {
      return _authStore.username;
    }

    function Login(username) {
      _authStore.username = username;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: if anyone could let me know the reason why my initial approach failed. it would be a gr8 help.
Thanks in advance